# Can you share an outgoing phone call between video room participants?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to share an outgoing phone call made by a video room participant with all other remote participants. It appears to be the only way a group of users can share a phone call is using Twilio's conference.

Is there a way to share an outgoing call with the video chat room participants?
To be clear, I want to share the sound of the call receiver with the chat room + having a single instance of a call so anyone can press hang up.

Imagine two participants in a room, participant A is making an outgoing phone call while participant B can listen, talk and hang up same as participant A.

What do you say?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [/Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), to initiate an outbound call and return TwiML that adds the participant to the Programmable Video room using the TwiML [Connect/Room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect) verb? You can then use the /Calls resource to [modify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress) that call leg as needed.